# How does Mac know an executable is from the outside world?

Tags: macos, mac, security, permissions, quarantine

This is just a curious question occurred to me yesterday while testing a program on other Macs.

When I build the program in xcode/terminal and run it, there is no warning dialog. But when I copy the executable to another Mac, there is a warning dialog.

So what specifies executable ownership and how it is detected by Mac?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/CodeSigningGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html

Comment: @Tetsujin I didn't enable code signing in xcode.

Comment: so you're trying to launch an unsigned app on another machine - Gatekeeper will stop you, unless the machine is set to allow apps from Anywhere.... but you asked 'how' & that is 'how'. Code Signing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is handled by the quarantine system in macOS. When a file is downloaded, the downloading program (browser, or whatever) attaches a special extended attribute to the file. When it's opened, Launch Services notices the quarantine attribute and applies some special security restrictions (such as the notice you're seeing).

See [Apple's developer release notes for OS X v10.5](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/content/releasenotes/Carbon/RN-LaunchServices/#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001369-CH1-DontLinkElementID_2_) (when quarantine was introduced). You can also see the extended attribute in Terminal with `ls -l@ /path/to/file`; it's the "com.apple.quarantine" one. You may also see "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemWhereFroms" and "com.apple.metadata:kMDItemDownloadedDate" attributes.